# What are the differences between Nearest Neighbor Algorithm and Greedy Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, nearest-neighbor, greedy

I'm trying to develop 2 different algorithms for Travelling Salesman Algorithm (TSP) which are Nearest Neighbor and Greedy. I can't figure out the differences between them while thinking about cities.

I think they will follow the same way because shortest path between two cities is greedy and the nearest at the same time. which part am i wrong? Can you explain with a few cities example thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is NN Algorithm basically creates segments to closest nodes that it can reach, Greedy is the method of it but it directly takes the node which is the closest to current node.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem
It gives an in depth description of the problem. There are many different solutions to the TSP, the Nearest Neighbour solution is a Greedy Solution, so these are indeed the same.

Comment: Well i kinda understand but i have an assingmnet and it says implement two different algorithms which are greedy and nearest neighbor algorithm so what is the point here then

Comment: I would go to the setter of the assignment and ask clarification!